# Getting the actual value of segment register in MASM

Tags: windows, assembly, x86-64, masm, position-independent-code

I'm trying to learn more about reading PEB / TEB (and segment registers in general).
My main source is: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Win32_Thread_Information_Block
I'm trying to figure out what's the actual address of any address in gs.
For instance, I see that the PEB in x64 is in gs:[60h]
so

```
mov rax, gs:[60h]
```

Should give me the address of the PEB. I'm trying to figure out where it is stored / what's the value of gs.

```
push gs  
pop rax                      ; rax = 43 (Memory is not defined @ 43)
; mov rax, gs:0h             ; Error : Operand must be memory expression
mov rax, gs                  ; rax = 43 
lea rax, gs:[0]              ; rax = 0 ?? should have been 43, or real address?
lea rax, gs:[30h]            ; rax = 48 -> why is that?
mov rax, gs:[30h]            ; getting TEB linear address 
mov rbx, [rax+60h]           ; getting PEB address using TEB linear address
mov rcx, gs:[60h]            ; rbx == rcx
```

My main questions are:

1) What are the values of 43 and 48 what they represent?

2) Is there a way to find and access the memory location of gs without gs:[30h]? since lea and gs:0 didn't work

3) I've tried assume nothing that didn't compile in my enviroment.

Enviroment: Windows 7, Visual Studio 2015

I've seen many references stating

Comment: 48 decimal = `30h`.  LEA *only* deals with the "offset" part of seg:off addresses.  You can't use it to read the segment base address (hidden internal thing set via WRMSR or `wrgsbase`), or the segment selector value = value in the architectural segment register (`mov eax, gs`).  You generally need a system call to portably query the linear address of the PEB / TEB, unless its own flat address is stored in the block somewhere.  `rdgsbase` would be usable if available, but it's new on like IvyBridge or something?

Comment: The value of the segment register is a *segment selector.*  It's an index into one of two tables (the LDT and the GDT) containing a description of the segments base address and limit.  You cannot find out the base address yourself.  In 64 bit mode, this is slightly more complicated because the base addresses of FS and GS are set through special instructions.  Yet, you still cannot figure them out directly on most processors.  While there are actually some new instructions to do so, I'm not familiar with them and they are not generally available.

Comment: Thanks guys for the comments. I'll read some one more about LDT and GDT tables. rdgsbase  seems like what I'm looking for. Wonder why it's only supported in newer architectures